# Force App Expiration

Tags: android, google-play

**Two Part Question:**

1. How do I do this for a mostly offline app (high level)?
2. Is it against policy or an expected / common practice?

The app in question, does not specifically require internet / store access to run. It is a free app, but requires in-app purchases to be useful.

**Reasoning:**
Basically, I do not want users on a version of the app that is too far out of date (say more than 2 or 3 versions, date dependent or both). The reasons are: The app will have regular reference material updates. I am also concerned that if security exploits are discovered, I have the ability to force the versions with a known exploit out of service. Is this a common practice to enforce version control on a mostly offline app and what is the high level model for doing this? Is it even an acceptable practice for Google Play Apps or is it on the fringe of Google's policies?

Comment: My answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386985/295004 so @mhdtouban is a valid answer. As the app is mostly offline, you may want to have a daily/weekly/monthly check to your own service/data file to see if the content is out of date and perhaps after a number of attempts at connecting to internet have a dialog indicating that the data is stale and may not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reasonably common practice, and not against policy. It is less common with mostly offline apps. It is most common games with a significant server component, as it is a hard maintenance burden to keep a server up to date so it works with all previous versions of the app. It does irritate users, especially ones who are often offline, and don't like the time or cost to download updates, so you may get more uninstalls.

As far as your first question, in a mostly offline app there are two good designs

1. The first design is time/date based. If you know your app has release cycles of a new version roughly every month say, have the app stop working after 3 months. This puts a ceiling on how old the app can be. This is easiest to code, and works best for completely offline users.
2. The second option is:

   - Make your app phone home to a server to check the required version whenever it is online.
   - Make the app check how long it has been since it has phoned home, and refuse to work after a certain length of time has elapsed (say a week)
   - For even better user experience, display to the user how long they have before they need to go online (Similar to Spotify offline mode, if you have ever used that)

This second option lets the user know exactly what is going on. In the case of a really bad security flaw, it also allows you to force an update more quickly. It is slightly harder to code, but not that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an API which will check the app current version and if it's older than the latest version on the store you can enable a force update dialog asking the user to download the latest release from the store. This usually happens on the splash screen when the user opens the app.

Comment: No one else is going to view this now cause some inconsiderate person voted to close without giving me the chance to alter. Can you please re-read the question (which I've edited) and modify your answer? I am fully aware that I can check for a latest version...

My question is more in regard to app that i don't want to force someone to be online to use. Appreciate your assistance. I am new to Google Play.

Comment: Am not quite sure I understand your use case. First to be able to get fresh data or to purchase you have to be online. 2nd you can't force update or shot down your app through Google play. So, the only solution is to do as I mentioned in my answer. If you think this answered your question please consider it a correct answer.

Comment: @mhtouban Maybe I'm looking for some sort of hybrid approach. I have an offline app that I don't want to get too out of date. I absolutely cannot require a connection every time. Though, I suppose I can check for one. The reference data is updated if an error is found. Also, is what you are suggesting against policy (to force an update)?

Comment: To have an api to check app version and explicitly ask the user to update the app before using it is totally fine.