# How to ask for forcefully update android app in webview

Tags: android, webview, auto-update

I have develop android app with webview which convert my website into android app. After launch there are some improvements in app. so I have done those improvements and again release with new version. Now i want my customers to update app forcefully. But app is develop fully in webview. So how can i do that?

Do I need to do code level changes in my website?

Do I need to create API to check app version and then ask for force update?

Is there any native code for this? if any let me know.

Comment: Sounds like: [How to force user to update the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47386846/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang you have provide link which suggest solution is for app develop in native which uses apis but my app is fully based on webview. So my website is convert to android / ios app.

Comment: Please provide more details on how website was converted to webview. If WebView via an app in the Play Store, then there is native code running the WebView, if progressive web app (PWA) then see: [When and how does a PWA update itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49739438/295004).

Comment: It is not PWA it is an app develop for convert website as a mobile app in webview

Answer (score -1):

This is what you can do:

```
1. In you android code, add a HTML Element in the webview
programmatically and set the app version. 

2.When you load the webapp on the server side, check for this element

3. If the element is set, then the webrequest is coming from the app

4. Then Check the version and show them a message if the version is not upto date.
```

Comment: i do not want to update my webview i want to ask user to update my app to latest version. And you have given answer to update browser.

Comment: @AdarshBhatt You don't have to update the webview, just show them a message then?

Comment: Updated Answer Above

Comment: Step above which you have provide that i know but i want proper solution with code example

Comment: You can hire someone another developer and pay them to build this feature? Because it probably would take a day or two to build it out.